# How to print value of a Variable using its memory address?

Tags: c++, memory

Suppose `0xfe2200` is the memory address of a variable `var2` and I want to display the value stored in it, E.g

```
cout<< "Value stored in the given address is :  " << 0xfe2200 << "    ";
```

I tried following but all in vain

```
cout << "Value is :  " << *0xfee2200 << " ;
cout << "Value is :  " << &0xfee200 << "  ;
```

Comment: Which is the type of `var2` ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "in vain".

Comment: type of variable is integer

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the address points to `int`, you may do:

```
cout << "Value is :  " << *reinterpret_cast<int*>(0xfee2200);
```

as literal `0xfee2200` is an interger type whereas you expected a pointer.

Comment: You should probably explain why the `reinterpret_cast *might* be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You have to decide as what **type of data** you want to interpret the memory content and **cast** it accordingly:

```
const char* tmp = "foofoo"; // Valid ptr for this example
const void* address = tmp; // Set to your address

const int* i = reinterpret_cast<const int*>(address);
const unsigned short* us = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned short*>(address);
const char* c = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(address);

std::cout << "i: " << (*i)
          << "\nus: " << (*us)
          << "\nc: " << (*c);
```

Output:

> i: 1718579046
>   us: 28518
>   c: f